# SQL Northwind database query duplicate rows

Tags: sql, duplicates

I am trying to create a query that will return message if the order has more products ordered than the in stock one but it has duplicates and I can't understand why. See the screenshot bellow: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLoTt.png)

The query is:

```
SELECT  a.OrderID, a.CustomerID,
(SELECT SUM(Subtotal) from [Order Subtotals] AS f 
  where a.OrderID = f.OrderID) as Total,
(Select SUM(Quantity) as Quantity from dbo.[Order Details Extended] b
  where a.OrderID = b.OrderID) as Quantity,
 ( SELECT
             CASE 
                  WHEN Quantity > d.UnitsInStock or Discontinued = 1 
                     THEN 'error in order' 
                  ELSE ''
             END AS varchar) as Messagee
FROM            dbo.Orders AS a

 Left join [Order Details Extended] as c on a.OrderID = c.OrderID
 Left join Products as d on c.ProductID = d.ProductID
```

Comment: Distinct would still return duplicates, for example, if one orderid is displaying three times and two of them are with empty messages then distinct would remove one of those but still display the other one + the one with error message

Comment: What result do you want when there are both "error in order" and not? Either skip that column and do SELECT DISTINCT. Or do a GROUP BY to pick your choice.

Comment: if there are both 'error in order' and empty message it should return just the 'error in order' one. If I add 'Select distinct case' it is still returning both.

Comment: Then do a GROUP BY!

Comment: Group by what? Can't group by messagee because it is not a valid column..

Comment: GROUP BY the other selected columns. Do MAX(Messagee) in the select list.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how would MAX on messagee look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right query is:

```
SELECT  a.OrderID, a.CustomerID, sum(os.subtotal) as Total,
 SUM(ode.Quantity) as quantity,
  CASE WHEN COUNT(
   CASE WHEN Quantity > pro.UnitsInStock OR Discontinued = 1 THEN 1 END
 ) > 0 THEN 'error in order' ELSE '' END AS Message
from dbo.Orders as a
Left join [Order Details Extended] as ode
on a.OrderID = ode.OrderID
Left join Products as pro
on ode.ProductID = pro.ProductID
left join [Order Subtotals] as os
on a.OrderID = os.OrderID

group by a.OrderID, a.CustomerID
```